# How can I get an instance of a cell defined in a storyboard without reuse identifier mechanism

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I'm already successfully getting an instance of my custom UITableViewCell (layout is defined in the storyboard cell prototype) in the table data source delegate, this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    LeaderboardCell* newCell = (LeaderboardCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"leaderboard_cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return newCell;

}
```

Since my application uses exactly the same cell layout **outside** the table view, I would like to allocate an instance of my LeaderboardCell cell from the storyboard. I already tried this, unsuccessfully (it returns a valid instance, but outlets are not connected):

```
LeaderboardCell* myRank = [[LeaderboardCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"leaderboard_cell"];
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where you have designed the cell in XIB file or in viewController storyboard?

Comment: I think what is happening is that initWithStyle is returning a default UITableViewCell, as LeaderboardCell will have inherited it from UITableViewCell, which will have no connections on it.You will have to create the cell in separate xib file and then load it from the xib, as your current LeaderboardCell may not have a xib associated with it while initialising it using above method.